# Aggregate based on multiple condition with overlap in R

Tags: r, aggregate

Hopefully, someone can help me :)

I have a (very big) dataset with 3 columns (ID, day and item), which has multiple rows per ID and day.

Simplified example (see reproducible sample below)

```
ID day item
A  1    xc
A  185  aa
B  1    xc
B  102  cc
B  102  aa
B  128  tg
C  55   xx
C  183  aa
```

I want to aggregate the data so that for every ID all the items are in a sequence of days.
**Note that (1)** for *each duplicate day* there should be a new sequence (i.e., items from the same day cannot be in the sequence) **and (2)** the sequence should *not be more than 182 days apart*.

Like so...

```
ID items
A   xc 
A   aa
B   xc, cc, tg
B   xc, aa, tg
C   xx, aa
```

My programming skills and knowledge are limited so I went down several rabbit holes... Can anyone help?

Ps. I posted the full length of what I need [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67518726/identify-which-group-has-sequence-of-events-while-ignoring-duplicate-dates). Hopefully dividing it into manageable pieces makes it more comprehensible / I think I can manage if the above issue is resolved.

---

**Reproducible sample data**
(contains multiple items per row in case on the same day)

```
DT <-    structure(list(items = c("bxM01, T-Other", "bxD01", "S-In", 
"bxD02", "L-I", "A9", "R-S, bxR01, bxR03", 
"bxA02", "HDTR", "S-In", "HVAL", "SC.R", "bxD11, S-Other", 
"SC.R", "K-Other", "bxD06, S-In", "A-s.spec", "LON", 
"bxJ01", "S-Other", "HVAL, SC.R", "bxN02, bxN02, bxC07, S-Other", 
"K-Other", "A-s.spec", "bxC09", "R-all-rhin", "S-S, bxD07, bxD01", 
"S-In", "bxD07, ECZM", "X-resp-prev", "bxD07", "HVAL", 
"T-Other", "bxA11", "HVAL", "HVAL", "P-S", "K-Other", 
"bxN01, NKSH", "A-s.spec", "bxJ01", "X-resp-prev", "D-S", 
"FYS, B-Other", "K-Other", "bxC07, RON, NKSH", "bxM01, bxA01", 
"bxS01", "NKSH", "T-Other", "bxC08", "bxD04, K-Other", "bxN02", 
"bxD07, Y-S", "bxD07, bxR06, ALGY", "bxJ01", "SC.R, S-In", 
"bxD10", "bxD10", "bxJ01", "SC.R", "S-In", "L-I", 
"Y-S", "S-S", "K-Other", "bxR03, LON", "S-In", 
"RON, S-Ne", "S-In", "S-In", "SC.R", 
"S-In", "S-Other", "Z-S", "SX", "NKSH", "F-In, bxS01", 
"N-Other", "FYS, NKSH", "bxN02, TROT", "S-Sdf", "OBES", 
"bxJ01, bxN02, K-Other", "bxR01, LAB, TROT", "OBES", "K-Other", 
"A-Unknown", "Z-S", "K-S", "OBES", "bxM01, bxA02", 
"SC.R", "L-Other", "bxD02", "X-Other", "bxN05", "bxR06", 
"bxJ01, bxA02, bxN02", "TROT"), days = c(613L, 861L, 883L, 
1210L, 1408L, 1699L, 391L, 409L, 745L, 1448L, 28L, 32L, 43L, 
98L, 105L, 231L, 439L, 442L, 446L, 544L, 704L, 801L, 845L, 846L, 
851L, 1097L, 1131L, 1168L, 1246L, 1264L, 1309L, 1313L, 1323L, 
1327L, 1452L, 1475L, 1482L, 1484L, 1518L, 1588L, 1629L, 1630L, 
1631L, 1634L, 1641L, 1645L, 1699L, 1727L, 1741L, 1769L, 1809L, 
28L, 790L, 953L, 999L, 1004L, 1013L, 1015L, 1034L, 1055L, 1168L, 
1190L, 1211L, 1375L, 1544L, 1802L, 241L, 353L, 416L, 437L, 451L, 
547L, 548L, 706L, 831L, 832L, 839L, 1099L, 1276L, 1301L, 1567L, 
1598L, 287L, 574L, 854L, 872L, 943L, 1089L, 1147L, 1170L, 1177L, 
1201L, 1202L, 1512L, 20L, 30L, 52L, 53L, 87L, 309L), ID = c("G", 
"G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "F", "F", "F", "F", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
"E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
"E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", 
"E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A")), row.names = c(NA, -100L
), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

**Unnesting to get one item per day**

```
DT <- DT %>% 
mutate(items = strsplit(as.character(items), ",")) %>% 
unnest(items)
```

---

**** **EDIT** ****

Don't know if this is helpful, but I tried the following, but got stuck again:

```
# gives unique events in one day a unique number
DT[(duplicated(DT, by = c("ID", "day")) | duplicated(DT, by = c("id", "day"), fromLast=TRUE)), Dup_val := 1]

# put different sequence (1,2,3,4......) for duplicated and 0 for non duplicated (item that only has single item in the list)
DT[!is.na(Dup_val), Dup_val := seq_len(.N), by = ID]
DT[is.na(Dup_val), Dup_val := 0]
```

---

**** **EDIT** ****

**Expected outcome based on DT (first 11 lines)**

```
     ID     items                
#1:  A      bxD02, X-Other, bxN05, bxN06, bxJ01              
#2:  A      bxD02, X-Other, bxN05, bxN06, bxA02            
#3:  A      bxD02, X-Other, bxN05, bxN06, bxN02              
#4:  A      TROT                 
#5:  B      OBES                 
#6:  B      bxJ01
#7:  B      bxN02
#8:  B      K-Other
#9:  B      bxR01, OBES    
#10: B      LAB, OBES
#11: B      TROT, OBES
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've managed to get the sequences the way I need them as described above and also select the sequences as I need them (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67518726/identify-which-group-has-sequence-of-events-while-ignoring-duplicate-dates)). While I think there should be a more efficient way I am posting the answer for however needs it. If anyone has a suggestion for making this more efficient, please post it too.

```
# create a column with same number for duplicate days 
DT[(duplicated(DT, by = c("ID", "days")) | duplicated(DT, by = c("ID", "days"), fromLast=TRUE)), Dup_val := 1]
DT[!is.na(Dup_val), Dup_val := seq_len(.N), by = ID]
DT[is.na(Dup_val), Dup_val := 0]
max(DT$Dup_val) # is 15, so I make 15 subsets below.

# subset all duplicate days (>0) + all non-duplicates (0)
DT1 <- DT[Dup_val == 0 | Dup_val == 1]
DT2 <- DT[Dup_val == 0 | Dup_val == 2]
DT3 <- DT[Dup_val == 0 | Dup_val == 3]
DT4 <- DT[Dup_val == 0 | Dup_val == 4]
DT5 <- DT[Dup_val == 0 | Dup_val == 5]
DT6 <- DT[Dup_val == 0 | Dup_val == 6]
DT7 <- DT[Dup_val == 0 | Dup_val == 7]
DT8 <- DT[Dup_val == 0 | Dup_val == 8]
DT9 <- DT[Dup_val == 0 | Dup_val == 9]
DT10 <- DT[Dup_val == 0 | Dup_val == 10]
DT11 <- DT[Dup_val == 0 | Dup_val == 11]
DT12 <- DT[Dup_val == 0 | Dup_val == 12]
DT13 <- DT[Dup_val == 0 | Dup_val == 13]
DT14 <- DT[Dup_val == 0 | Dup_val == 14]
DT15 <- DT[Dup_val == 0 | Dup_val == 15]

# create column indicating if 182 days apart
DT1[, grp := cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(days) >= 182)), ID]
DT1=DT1[, .(items = toString(unique(items))), .(ID, grp)]
DT2[, grp := cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(days) >= 182)), ID]
DT2=DT2[, .(items = toString(unique(items))), .(ID, grp)]
DT3[, grp := cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(days) >= 182)), ID]
DT3=DT3[, .(items = toString(unique(items))), .(ID, grp)]
DT4[, grp := cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(days) >= 182)), ID]
DT4=DT4[, .(items = toString(unique(items))), .(ID, grp)]
DT5[, grp := cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(days) >= 182)), ID]
DT5=DT5[, .(items = toString(unique(items))), .(ID, grp)]
DT6[, grp := cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(days) >= 182)), ID]
DT6=DT6[, .(items = toString(unique(items))), .(ID, grp)]
DT7[, grp := cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(days) >= 182)), ID]
DT7=DT7[, .(items = toString(unique(items))), .(ID, grp)]
DT8[, grp := cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(days) >= 182)), ID]
DT8=DT8[, .(items = toString(unique(items))), .(ID, grp)]
DT9[, grp := cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(days) >= 182)), ID]
DT9=DT9[, .(items = toString(unique(items))), .(ID, grp)]
DT10[, grp := cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(days) >= 182)), ID]
DT10=DT10[, .(items = toString(unique(items))), .(ID, grp)]
DT11[, grp := cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(days) >= 182)), ID]
DT11=DT11[, .(items = toString(unique(items))), .(ID, grp)]
DT12[, grp := cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(days) >= 182)), ID]
DT12=DT12[, .(items = toString(unique(items))), .(ID, grp)]
DT13[, grp := cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(days) >= 182)), ID]
DT13=DT13[, .(items = toString(unique(items))), .(ID, grp)]
DT14[, grp := cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(days) >= 182)), ID]
DT14=DT14[, .(items = toString(unique(items))), .(ID, grp)]
DT15[, grp := cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(days) >= 182)), ID]
DT15=DT15[, .(items = toString(unique(items))), .(ID, grp)]

# row bind subsets
DT_seq <- rbindlist(list(DT1, DT2, DT3, DT4, DT5, DT6, DT7, DT8, DT9, DT10, DT11, DT12, DT13, DT14, DT15))
# remove duplicates
DT_seq = DT_seq[!duplicated(DT_seq, by = c("ID", "items"), fromLast = T)]
```